# Apache Maven Fluido Skin: Move "Last Published" and "Version" to the right

Tags: maven

I have the following `site.xml`:-

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/DECORATION/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/DECORATION/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/decoration-1.1.0.xsd">
    <bannerLeft>
        <name>Project Title</name>
        <href>http://maven.apache.org/</href>
    </bannerLeft>

    <skin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-fluido-skin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </skin>

    <custom>
        <fluidoSkin>
            <sourceLineNumbersEnabled>true</sourceLineNumbersEnabled>
            <breadcrumbDivider>»</breadcrumbDivider>
        </fluidoSkin>
    </custom>

    <body>
        <links>
            <item name="Link 1" href="#"/>
            <item name="Link 2" href="#"/>
            <item name="Link 3" href="#"/>
        </links>

        <breadcrumbs>
            <item name="Crumb 1" href="#"/>
            <item name="Crumb 2" href="#"/>
            <item name="Crumb 3" href="#"/>
        </breadcrumbs>

        <menu ref="reports"/>

    </body>
</project>
```

... and `mvn site` generates the following look and feel:-

[image]

How do I move the "Last Published" and "Version" to the right side, just like what I see from [Apache Maven Fluido Skin](http://maven.apache.org/skins/maven-fluido-skin/) itself?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following tags as children of `<project>`:

```
<publishDate position="right"/>
<version position="right"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the things which are in the site descriptor can be found here:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/sitedescriptor.html